# Glossy See through web graphic

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What's the best way to create something similar to the panel that the controller sits in:

[image: Example image]

This is for the web and using photoshop.

I think the gist of it is an inner glow on a low opacity background, what I'm struggling with is that the glow/stroke almost looks like a gradient and I'm not sure how to achieve this. Would it be a mask of some kind?

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this kind of effect? I think I understand the bulk of it, but I'm struggling to achieve a similar level of polish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradients can have a transparency too. Check out the layer style for gradient overlay (while making the layer itself 0% fill).

There are many tutorials (e.g. google for layer style, gradient, transparency, tutorial), but this specific style can all be done in layer styles with trying around just a bit.

Feel free to ask if you are stuck at a specific point.

Edit:
[image]

This is one shape layer with:

- inner glow
- 1px stroke
- gradient overlay
- drop shadow